# Finding the limiting distribution of sample covariance

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

How can I find the limiting / asymptotic distribution of

$\sqrt{n}(\hat{\sigma}_{XY}-\sigma_{XY})$,

provided

$\sigma_{XY}=E[(X-\mu_X)(Y-\mu_Y)]$ and $\hat{\sigma}_{XY} = n^{-1}\sum(X_i-\bar{X})(Y_i-\bar{Y})$ by definition?

If this is related to matrix since we talk about joint distribution, I would like to ask you how should I build up the step.

Plus, if there is a condition that $E[X^4]$ and $E[Y^4]$ - in other words, kurtoses - are finite, does it change my answer?

Comment: I think that the first equation on the second page here: stat.psu.edu/~dhunter/asymp/fall2002/lectures/ln08 gives you what you want.

Comment: can't you use the delta method for this?